# Android App installs with API 24, but will not for API 19 (Jack toolchain issue?)

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk

I'm somewhat new to android dev, so i'm having some issues developing for multiple API's. When I created my project, I set the minimum API level to 18 which isn't even supported anymore (according to a wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history)

I tested the installation of an APK on two different phones, both were API 24, and there were no issues. However, my associate with API 19 cannot install the application. Apparently it gave him the informative error of "App not installed."

For testing purposes, I created a new project, and without adding any code (Leaving only Android Studio's generated "Hello World" label), generated a signed APK, then sent that out to my associate. He failed to install that as well.

The only other thing of note was that I played around with enabling "jack." I was testing out some random source code which required it. I wonder if that would cause problems? That is hard to believe with an empty project.

More specifically, I had this error when testing the source code mentioned above "Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8." So, I enabled Jack, of course.

Here is the build.gradle (if that helps?)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.random.name"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Any thoughts are highly appreciated!

Comment: Out of curiosity, has your colleague tried running the app from within AndroidStudio? If that fails as well you might get a more detailed error message.

Comment: @drawinfinity In short - no. He recently uninstalled Android Studio, but I have already urged him to reinstall. Like you said, the generated error code will help a lot!

Comment: warning, jack is deprecated officially by google: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/jackandjill

Comment: I tried to disable Jack due to finding that out later. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use java 8 in your project, java 8 doesn't work on API level 18 also you need to enable jack toolchain for that

source: https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

though if you would like to use java 8 features you can use retrolambda with gradle 
https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda

For now if you're not using any java 8 features, then just change source compatibility in your gradle file to java 7 instead of java 8 and it should work fine.

use this

```
compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

instead of

```
compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

it can be pasted in your gradle file like:

```
 android {
 ...
 defaultConfig {
 ...

 }
 compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 }
}
```

Comment: So, it seems my problem was that my "build.gradle" file was not showing the compileOptions... I would have been able to play around and figure this out if it had. Just weird!

I ended up reinstalling Android Studio - but I tested adding Version 1.8 to see what it would say, and yep - it was asking to install Jack. When I changed it to 1.7, it didn't say anything.. and didn't ask to refresh Gradle. That means, that Android Studio automatically has us set up for 1.7.

Thanks for the reply, i'll accept this!